# Postfix mail server failed email sending(First setup)

Tags: postfix

I've went through the article below step by step in order to make Postfix up and running on Ubuntu 14.04:

[PostfixVirtualMailBoxClamSmtpHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixVirtualMailBoxClamSmtpHowto)

Now in the step where it says to use `mail` command to send email I send it. The command I enter:

```
root@myDomain# mail info@mydomain.com
Subject: test subj
test it

.
Cc:
```

Now I should have a new folder as below:

```
/home/vmail/mydomain/info/new
```

I cannot see such an email. I can telnet to 25 port:

```
root@mydomain:~# telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo localhost
250-yadme.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

Postfix server is running. The `/var/log/mail.log` says:

```
Jan 17 12:03:45 mydomain postfix/cleanup[26044]: 269F63E0E9: message-id=<20160117120345.269F63E0E9@mydomain.com>
Jan 17 12:03:45 mydomain postfix/qmgr[26030]: 269F63E0E9: from=<root@mydomain.com>, size=291, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 17 12:03:45 mydomain postfix/trivial-rewrite[26045]: warning: do not list domain mydomain.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Jan 17 12:03:45 mydomain postfix/local[26046]: 269F63E0E9: to=<info@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.1, delays=0.08/0/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "info")
Jan 17 12:03:45 mydomain postfix/cleanup[26044]: 34BBA3E0EA: message-id=<20160117120345.34BBA3E0EA@mydomain.com>
Jan 17 12:03:45 mydomain postfix/qmgr[26030]: 34BBA3E0EA: from=<>, size=1916, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 17 12:03:45 mydomain postfix/bounce[26047]: 269F63E0E9: sender non-delivery notification: 34BBA3E0EA
Jan 17 12:03:45 mydomain postfix/qmgr[26030]: 269F63E0E9: removed
Jan 17 12:03:45 mydomain postfix/local[26046]: 34BBA3E0EA: to=<root@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan 17 12:03:45 mydomain postfix/qmgr[26030]: 34BBA3E0EA: removed
```

The below parameters are the one I've added to `main.cf`:

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```

I have added `MX` record if that helps.
What should I do now? I couldn't think of something that I've done wrong? What I'm missing?

**EDIT:**
The below command query `info` user:

```
postmap -q info@mydomain.com hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
```

it outputs:

```
mydomain.com/info/
```

I removed all the domain in front of `mydestination =`. Now `mail.log` says:

```
Jan 17 13:20:07 mydomain postfix/pickup[26583]: 8E3803E0E4: uid=0 from=<root>
Jan 17 13:20:07 mydomain postfix/cleanup[26588]: 8E3803E0E4: message-id=<20160117132007.8E3803E0E4@mydomain.com>
Jan 17 13:20:07 mydomain postfix/qmgr[26584]: 8E3803E0E4: from=<root@mydomain.com>, size=282, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 17 13:20:07 mydomain postfix/virtual[26590]: 8E3803E0E4: to=<info@mydomain.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.08, delays=0.06/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan 17 13:20:07 mydomain postfix/qmgr[26584]: 8E3803E0E4: removed
```

BUT inside of `~/Maildir` is empty. There is not folder named `mydomain/info`. There 3 folders named: `tmp`, `new`, `cur`. Now what is happening?

Comment: Your logs tell you clearly what the issue is - `unknown user: "info"`.

Comment: @JennyD, I have that user in vmap

Comment: @JennyD please take time to see the edit part.

Comment: Did you do `ls -la` or just `ls`?

Comment: @JennyD, problem is solved as in above config you can see I've set `virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail `. so I was looking in a wrong place `~/Maildir`!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!

As in the above config you can see I've set `virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail`, so I was looking in a wrong place `~/Maildir`